# hash replace except specific url in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a hash replaced jQuery to work on my accordion.

```
var hash = window.location.hash;
var _hash = hash.replace(/#/, '');
```

However, I have also got a hash link (/hello#let-us) in my navigation to scroll to the div with id=let-us. How do I change the above jQuery to filter the hash replace(replacing all hash links except '/hello#let-us')?

Comment: Are you saying that you want `/hello#let-us` to become `/hello`?

Comment: @ScottHarris Sorry, Scott. I dont want /hello#let-us to become /hello. I want all other # replaced except /hello#let-us

Comment: this has nothing to do with jQuery which has no string manipulation methods

Comment: @charlietfl [none](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.trim/)? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just check the result of `_hash`... If jQuery is used then http://api.jquery.com/jquery.inarray/

```
var toCheck = ['let-us', 'another-value'];
if ($.inArray(_hash, toCheck) == -1) {
 // hash is not in array toCheck
}
```